# Division and Ratios in SQl

Tags: mysql, sql

This gives me  what I am looking for just showing how many Males and Females. I am trying to get the ratio of Males/Females. Is there any easy way to do that? And have it show two digits after the decimal?

```
select gender,count (*)

from HumanResources.Employee

group by gender
```

Answer (score 2):

Leaving formatting to an application level problem:

```
SELECT sum(gender='Males')/sum(gender='Females')
FROM HumanResources.Employee
```

`gender=X` is a boolean expression, either 1 (true) or 0 (false) is why this works.

Obvious this misses the non-male/female emploees.

Comment: This is saying incorrect syntax and won't even run.

Comment: [testing says otherwise](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=dE3KyR15jc). Perhaps include your 'show create table Employee' in the question and comment on the exact error you are getting.

Comment: @PaceWasden . . . This is correct syntax in MySQL, which is the database tagged on your question.  If you have a different database, I would suggest asking a *new* question.  This question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you want

```
select gender, count(*), 
cast(count(*)*100 ::float/ (select count(*) from HumanResources.Employee)::float as decimal(5,2))
from HumanResources.Employee
group by gender
```

Comment: its not tagged postgres so there's no ::float in MySQL